# How do I change the site root

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used absolute links throughout my site, the problem comes when I am trying to set up a testing version in a subdirectory on another server. For example, the document structure is /images/image.jpg on the live server, but /subdirectory/images/image.jpg on the testing folder.

What is the solution? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use subfolders, use subdomains instead. Even on shared hosting you typically have the ability to set these up. It takes all of a few minutes, and you dont have to modify anything in your project.

Answer (score 2):

**dirty and fast answer**: use symlink

Move everything to /images/ and  run this :

```
 ln -s /images/ /subdirectory/images/
```

**clean and slower answer**: define a constant on a constant file. Use constants everywhere as a suffix to file location. Change the constant file for live

**Best Answer**: replicate environments (dev = live).

Answer (score 1):

Just do a var_dump($_SERVER) which is a array that stores a lot of server related variables. You will come up with something like

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']
```

read http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for a list of SERVER vars

Comment: and what is the aim once these server variables have been attained?

Comment: They give you values like http://  myserver etc so you can combine them http://myserver/index.php